# Why are the graphs of the inverses of trigonometric function incomplete

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

For example, let's take a look at arcsin.

If I try to graph arcsin(x) in a graphing calculator. It turns out like this ([Graph of arcsin(x) in GeoGebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr6rh.png)). Shouldn't it look more like this ([Graph of x=sin(y) in GeoGebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGUhS.png)) since y=arcsin(x) is the same equation as x=sin(y)? Why does it stop like that? I comprehend that in order for an equation to be a function every point on the x-axis must have exactly one image on the y-axis, but wouldn't that just mean arcsin, arccos and arctan aren't functions?

Comment: It is because it is not an inverse of $\sin:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, or even of $\sin:\mathbb{R}\to[-1,1]$ if your definition of function considers this a different function, which don't have inverses. It is the inverse of $\sin:[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\to[-1,1]$.

Comment: Your first graph is the graph of a **function in x**, which means that each element in the domain gets mapped to exactly one element in the function's range.  Your second graph is a graph of a **mapping that is not a function in x**.  Instead, the second graph is a function in y.

Comment: Because $\arcsin$ is a function, it can only take one value for any input. That is the definition of a function.

Comment: Another way to say the same things as my colleagues is that sine function has **monotony intervals** such as $[- \pi/2,\pi/2], \ [\pi/2, 3\pi/2],  \ [3\pi/2, 5\pi/2]$, etc. where it is always increasing, always decreasing, always increasing, etc. resp.. It is the first interval $[- \pi/2,\pi/2]$ that has been chosen (for excellent reasons) as the reference part for taking the inverse of sine function (but once again, the restriction of sine function on this precise interval).

Comment: If someone says "I'm thinking of an angle whose tangent is $1$", it's not fair for them to ask "What's my angle?" and expect a correct guess, as there are infinitely-many choices. But all of the choices are related in a specific way, so that you can give an answer built around a "principal" value: "Your angle is $\pi/4$ ... plus some multiple of $\pi$." We *define* arctangent to give the principal angle. This is not unlike someone thinking of a number whose square is $25$ and you responding: "Your number is $5$ ... plus-or-minus." We *define* $\sqrt{25}$ to be $5$, the *principal* square root.

Comment: Worth noting: Eventually, you'll learn about (contradictorily-named) "multi-valued functions" that return, say, every angle whose tangent is $1$, or every number whose square is $25$. We typically restrict a multi-valued function to be a *proper* (single-valued) function by specifying a "branch" of values we prefer. For example, the multi-valued square root has a "positive" branch and a "negative" branch. If someone prefers the latter, they'd want you to say that the square root of $25$ is $-5$. This is not unlike, say, asking specifically for the *third-quadrant angle* whose tangent is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually no, $x=\sin(y)$ is not equivalent to $y=\arcsin(x)$. Someone told you that $\arcsin$ is the inverse of $\sin$, but as you've noticed $\sin$ does not have an inverse. By definition $y=\arcsin(x)$ if and only if $x=\sin(y)$ *and* $-\pi/2\le y\le\pi/2$.